# Handling click events for dynamically created buttons in array

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I have an array of buttons that are created through code. The reason why I've done this is because the amount of buttons could change, and in this case, I'm trying to create buttons that are displayed as days in a month on a calendar, and the amount can't be at a set amount because if the amount of buttons were being created for February, the amount would either be 28 or 29.

I've done this how I want to, however the problem comes at having to handle a click event for each button. Since I'm looking for the general idea how to handle a click event in the below example, I want to messagebox what the content is for the button.

```
Dim btns(Date.DaysInMonth(CurrentYear, CurrentMonth) - 1) As Button

For ButtonCount As Integer To btns.Length
      btns(ButtonCount) = New Button With {.Content = ButtonCount}

      'Handler goes here.
Next
```

The way that I reference these buttons individually is through btns(ButtonCount), I do not name them.

So is there a way to add a click event to these buttons created in the example?

Comment: Have a look at the  `AddHandler` and `RemoveHandler` statements. You can use them dynamically. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7taxzxka.aspx

Comment: You must call `btns.Length - 1` in your loop pr else you'll get an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Use the AddHandler statement to assign an event handler to your button. In your event handler check which button was pressed.

Comment: You should probably add a code example to make this answer even more _"an answer"_.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, take a look at the documentation as suggested in the comments.
[(AddHandler Doc.)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/6yyk8z93(v=vs.90).aspx)

Second, you could follow this example to achieve what you want to do:

```
Dim btns(Date.DaysInMonth(CurrentYear, CurrentMonth) - 1) As Button

For ButtonCount As Integer To btns.Length - 1
      btns(ButtonCount) = New Button With {.Content = ButtonCount}

      AddHandler btns(ButtonCount).Click, AddressOf OnBtnClick
Next

Private Sub OnBtnClick(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
       'Your Event Handling
End Sub
```